# ADFS - how to create outgoing claims with conditional values

Tags: adfs

I am fairly new to ADFS. I understand how to set up issuance claim rules for 'Send group membership as a claim" in the ADFS Management app. But I now have a situation where I have several ad groups that I need to check for and send outgoing values for the same outgoing claim type based on priority. For example a user could be in 2 different groups and one group gets a higher value than the other and would "override" the lower value. I know I can set up rules for both and have the higher one listed first but then the vendor picks up both values. I only want to send across one value (basically an if/then/else type of logic). How would I do this?

Comment: There isn't really an if - then - else. Sometimes you can get around this with Exists, NotExists.

Answer (score 0):

For two groups P1 and P2:

Issue P1 if there is one.

c1:[Type == "http://contoso.com/P1"]
=> issue(Type="http://contoso.com/P1", Value=c1.value);

Use a "NOT EXISTS" rule.

NOT EXISTS([Type == "http://contoso.com/P1"])
=> add(Type = "http://contoso.com/noP1", Value = "No");

The value is not important. We just want a claim.

c1:[Type == "http://contoso.com/noP1"] &&
c2:[Type == "http://contoso.com/P2"]
=> issue(Type="http://contoso.com/P2", Value=c2.value);